# Sql conditional sum computation on other column value check

Tags: sql-server, sum

i have following sql query.

```
SELECT (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Qty),0) 
From Bills 
JOIN BillMaster on Bills.BillNumber = BillMaster.BillNumber 
where SessionID = '" + DBHandler.SessionID(Date) + "' 
and BillMaster.ShiftID = " + SHiftID + " 
and Bills.ProductID = products.id ) [qty], 
products.price , products.name 
FROM products.
```

In "Bills" table there is column "isDeal". I want that sum will execute only when "isDeal" = 0 
I attached Bills table screenshot in which it can be seen that there is column "isDeal"[image]
and i am attaching output report where i want that when isDeal = 0 then sum will compute other wise sum shouldn't compute
[image]
so how can i compute this ?

Comment: Use a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Please update your question and show us sample input and output data.

Comment: I updated my question please see the updated question @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT 
    isnull((
    SELECT SUM(Qty)
    From Bills 
    inner JOIN BillMaster on Bills.BillNumber = BillMaster.BillNumber 
    where SessionID = '" + DBHandler.SessionID(Date) + "' 
    and BillMaster.ShiftID = " + SHiftID + " 
    and Bills.ProductID = products.id and isdeal=0 
    ), 0) [qty],  
products.price , products.name 
FROM products
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query:

```
SELECT (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(
CASE 
    WHEN IsDeal =0 THEN Qty
    ELSE 0
END,0)
),0) 
From Bills 
JOIN BillMaster on Bills.BillNumber = BillMaster.BillNumber 
where SessionID = '" + DBHandler.SessionID(Date) + "' 
and BillMaster.ShiftID = " + SHiftID + " 
and Bills.ProductID = products.id ) [qty], 
products.price , products.name 
FROM products
```

Comment: It is still giving an error. it's not fetching the results properly in my c# desktop application

Comment: error is "the ISNULL function requires 2 arguments"

Answer (score 0):

other method :

```
SELECT ISNULL(f2.Qty, 0) qty, f1.price , f1.name 
FROM products f1
outer apply
( select SUM(Qty) qty
  From Bills 
  inner JOIN BillMaster on Bills.BillNumber = BillMaster.BillNumber 
  where SessionID = '" + DBHandler.SessionID(Date) + "' 
  and BillMaster.ShiftID = " + SHiftID + " 
  and Bills.ProductID = f1.id and IsDeal =0
) f2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation on `isDeal`:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN isDeal = 0 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END), 0) 
     FROM Bills t1
     INNER JOIN BillMaster t2
         ON t1.BillNumber = t2.BillNumber 
     WHERE SessionID = '" + DBHandler.SessionID(Date) + "' AND
           t2.ShiftID = " + SHiftID + " AND
           t1.ProductID = products.id
    ) [qty], 
    products.price,
    products.name 
FROM products
```